# Typescript: convert array of strings to readonly array of literals

Tags: arrays, typescript

Is there any possibility to convert already defined array of strings (`string[]`) to readonly array of literals?

Something like:

```
const arr = ["a", "b"]
const readonlyArr = arr as const
```

(which doesnt work of course)

I know, that `const readonlyArr = ["a", "b"] as const` works, but thats not what i want...

Thanks!

Comment: How would the literals be inferred if their type has been widened to `string[]` from a past assignment?

Comment: You can only do the inverse: to define an array of literals as const before declaring another variable using this array, because the array can still be mutated at runtime. You can still `.push()`, `.pop()`, or even `arr[0] = 'c'` even if the variable is declared as `const`.

Comment: do the inverse is actually a good idea! Thanks!
`const readonlyArr = ["a", "b"] as const;`
`const arr = readonlyArr as unknown as string[];`

Comment: If you are declaring a read-only array, `const arr: readonly string[] = readonlyArr;` should work as type widening can be done automatically.